# Chrome displaying dom elements in strange order, then fixed on refresh

Tags: html, google-chrome

This must be a content problem, but so far I haven't found it - and it is new, it just started happening on a production site. 
Using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m, I can replicate this pretty regularly, and so far, not in any other browser. 
the problem is on load, some dom elements are appearing out of order. That is, the dom has div1, div2, table1, div3, table2, etc., but the rendered web page shows table 2 above div1. There is not, as far as I can tell, any css that is causing it to be positioned strangely, and simply refreshing the page makes it render correctly. There are not errors in the console. 
One caveat - the html is the output of a conglomerate of software and developers, and is not the best dom structure to begin with. But again, it is fine in all other browsers (so far), and it was fine in Chrome until recently. 
Below are two screenshots* - the source, and the rendered output. Note that in the source, the H3 tag with the words "Items In Your Shopping Cart Below" appears above the highlighted element (the table containing the checkout button). But in the rendered html, you can see that the button is above the H3. Again, if I refresh the page, it fixes itself.

I am still troubleshooting this, will keep trying to find the problem, but hoping someone out there might have some idea what could be going on. I suspect it is to do with the carousel of images at the top, but that's been in use, unchanged, for a long time now, so not sure what's changed.

- Shoot, I don't have the right creds to post images in my question! Here are links to the images:
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4prpoinmc83f00/Chrome%20Cart%20Bug%20Source.png
  and
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j092l7e1etebz07/Chrome%20Cart%20Bug%20Rendered.png

You can also (probably) reproduce this yourself. Got to www.storkie.com, and add something to your cart. No, I'm not trying to lure you into shopping there - just that's how to get to the problem. Anyway, it may come up fine on first add, but then, if you click the View Cart link at the top, it probably will come up as in the pictures.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you give us some code? Or you want a theoretical answer?

Comment: Well, that's why I gave the screenshot showing the source html. The code is outputting the same html regardless, just sometimes it is displaying correctly and sometimes not. So, I'm open to providing more detail, but not sure exactly what to provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue on a JSF Primefaces application and I couldn't find any unescaped characters.

The element order on my page changes every third or fourth reload, BUT I have an ajax poll (refresh) every 15 seconds and when this hits the page renders correctly.

I compared the source code before and after this ajax refresh, but there were no differences.

I know this is no solution, but maybe helps to get closer to one.

Edit:

I found an issue in chromium issue tracker regarding this problem.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322936&q=order&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

In any case, the issue should be fixed in next chrome version.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that I have the exact same problem. A site that was last updated six months ago has recently started rendering elements out of order in Chrome.

For me it happens 2 out of 3 times I visit the page and it's as if rendering restarts when it hits a specific tag.

My code look kinda like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack..." class="HistoryLink">List</a>
<span class="HistoryLink_Separator">&nbsp;»&nbsp;</span>
<span class="HistoryLink_Last>Item</span>
```

Chrome renders the page fine until it hits the SPAN with the » (right double angle quotes) then it starts positioning elements at the very top of the page again.

Comment: Thank you! While it doesn't confirm that I'm not crazy, it does lend some support, that at least someone else is seeing this same problem. Could it be related to the rdaquo? I will have to check and see if I have any of those - or other unescaped entities - in my page. Thanks for the response.