# How do I stick my footer to bottom of the page with Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an old website and I recently added a footer menu to this website. The footer menu should be at the footer of the website, below everything else. But I found out that with Google Chrome, the footer appears too high - above some parts of my website. I tried and didn't find a way to fix it. I tried adding "`<center>`" before the footer, but it doesn't solve the problem.

I tested this on different browsers and found following results:

- with Google Chrome Canary it's fine
- with FireFox and Internet Explorer it's fine
- with Opera and Safari it's fine
- with Google Chrome it's **not working**

I checked this on two computers (with Windows, Google Chrome version 31.0.1650.63 m). The Canary version is 34.0.1768.0 canary and there it looks fine.

The footer contains tables and some other HTML elements, I tried to disable the CSS but it doesn't solve the problem. Do you know how to make the footer appear at the footer of the website? The link of the page is http://www.speedysoftware.com/composer/appendix-7/, and the same problem appears on a few pages of [this website](http://www.speedysoftware.com/composer/).

This is the HTML of the footer:

```
<center>
<div class="footer" id="footer">

<div class="links_table" >
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="bottomlinks" dir="ltr">
<tbody><tr align="center" valign="top">
<td align="center" width="100%">

<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" border="0" dir="ltr">

<tbody><tr align="center" valign="top"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" dir="ltr"><tbody><tr align="center" valign="bottom">
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedy.net/about/" title="About">About</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedy.net/privacy/" title="Privacy">Privacy</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedy.net/terms/" title="Terms of Service">Terms</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedy.net/contact/" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://sourceforge.net/project/project_donations.php?group_id=57192" title="Donate to Speedy Composer">Donate</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table></td></tr>

<tr align="center" valign="top"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr align="center" valign="top"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" dir="ltr"><tbody><tr align="center" valign="bottom">
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedy.net/" title="Speedy Net">Speedy Net</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedycomposer.com/" title="Speedy Composer">Speedy Composer</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedywhois.com/" title="Speedy Whois">Speedy Whois</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.speedy.net/wordpress/" title="Speedy Net WordPress">Speedy Net WordPress</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table></td></tr>

<tr align="center" valign="top"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr align="center" valign="top"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" dir="ltr"><tbody><tr align="center" valign="bottom">
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/speedynet" title="Speedy Net's Shop">Speedy Net's Shop</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/speedycomposer" title="Speedy Composer's Shop">Speedy Composer's Shop</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/speedy_s" title="Speedy S-logo Shop">Speedy S-logo Shop</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table></td></tr>

<tr align="center" valign="top"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr align="center" valign="top"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" dir="ltr"><tbody><tr align="center" valign="bottom">
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.php.net/" title="PHP">PHP</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.mysql.com/" title="MySQL">MySQL</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.java.com/" title="Java">Java</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/" title="MATLAB">MATLAB</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr">&nbsp;·&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" dir="ltr"><a href="http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/" title="Octave">Octave</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

</div>
</center>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.footer, .push {
    /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    /* height: 82px; */
    height: 102px;
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
    /* border-top: 1px solid #B2CAFA; */
    clear: both;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.footer table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3D70A3 !important;
}

.footer a:visited {
    color: #3D70A3 !important;
}

.footer a:link {
    color: #3D70A3 !important;
}

.footer a:active {
    color: #3D70A3 !important;
}

.footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer .links_table {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

I know the HTML is not completely valid, but this is an old website and I don't have the time to validate it. I just want the footer to be in the correct position in all browsers. Do you know how to fix this bug?

Comment: To better show the problem, please post an image

Comment: Is it safe to assume this is the last thing in your HTML document as well? The center tag is deprecated, MDN advises that you do not use it anymore. Although some browsers may support it, it is in the process of being dropped.

Comment: You may not wish to spend the time getting the code to validate, but your pages have numerous errors in them that can cause the browsers (which are being more rigorous) to render your pages in unexpected ways. Use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to fid the errors and fix them. Do this for one page and check the results. You will probably find that's what you need to do for all the misbehaving pages.

Comment: The html you've provided renders fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/BwJKG/1/ What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Graham Walters, check the original website with Google Chrome (the bug doesn't appear in the link you posted). Man of Snow, you can see the problem with Google Chrome if you refresh a few times. Anyway I understand this is a bug in Google Chrome and I will wait for Google to release a new (fixed) version of Google Chrome. I already see that this is fixed with Google Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's the chrome's bug in ordering elements.

[Chrome displaying dom elements in strange order, then fixed on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083474/chrome-displaying-dom-elements-in-strange-order-then-fixed-on-refresh)

When I change the center tag's styles in inspector (e.g. change display to different values) then it is rendered correctly.
Try to place the

```
<center>
...
</center>
```

with

```
<div style="margin: auto;">
...
</div>
```

And make your codes standard, as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll accept the answer because of the link to the Google Chrome bug - I understand it is fixed in future versions of Google Chrome and that's why the page is OK with Google Chrome Canary (which version is higher). The '<div style="margin: auto;">' doesn't solve the problem but I will wait until Google will release a new version of Chrome. Thank you!

Comment: @Uri chrome 32 released and guess what? Your website looks fine from here! ;)

Comment: Yes, I checked now with Chrome 32 and I see that this bug is fixed. No need to update my website. Thank you!